# Undeterministic std::system_error: what(): Operation not permitted

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads, std-system-error

I am trying to run my program and once in a few runs I get an error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted
```

My code is available here: https://github.com/Qabrt/turnstiles

gdb outputs:

```
Thread 31 "trivial_test" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to thread 31 (Thread 0x7fff8a7fc700 (LWP 8716))]
#0  0x00007ffff6e7f83b in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6e7f83b in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6e81081 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff78670e5 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler ()
    at /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-7.3.0-r3/work/gcc-7.3.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95
#3  0x00007ffff7864cb6 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=<optimized out>)
    at /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-7.3.0-r3/work/gcc-7.3.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:47
#4  0x00007ffff7864d01 in std::terminate ()
    at /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-7.3.0-r3/work/gcc-7.3.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:57
#5  0x00007ffff789243f in std::execute_native_thread_routine (__p=0x555555790f80)
    at /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-7.3.0-r3/work/gcc-7.3.0/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:91
#6  0x00007ffff7bbd96a in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff6f4d11f in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

g++ --version

```
g++ (Gentoo 7.3.0-r3 p1.4) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I am compiling with -lpthread flag:

```
/usr/bin/c++    -Wall -Wunused-function -Wwrite-strings -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wparentheses -Wsequence-point -Wno-system-headers -Werror -Winit-self  -g -O0 -fstack-protector-all -D_GLIBXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/trivial_test.dir/trivial_test.cpp.o  -o trivial_test ../libturnstile_lib.a -lpthread
```

How can I get more info about the problem?

Comment: Is your program linked dynamically to `libpthread.so` or statically to `libpthread.a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to find out if the error is coming from your function that is being run by `std::thread` or from `std::thread` itself. If your function throws an exception it will be caught by the `std::thread` launcher function, and terminate will be called. If you make your function `noexcept` then `terminate` will get called before it's caught, and you'll see where it's thrown from in the stack trace (later versions of GCC don't catch the exception, so this happens automatically).

If the exception is coming from `std::thread` itself it means that your program has linked to the dummy definition of `pthread_create` in `libc.so.6` instead of the real one in `libpthread.so` or `libpthread.a`

Use `ldd` to see if your program is linking to the shared `libpthread.so` or not. If it is, something's wrong with your toolchain (the definition in `libpthread.so` should get used instead of the weak symbol in `libc.so`). If you're linking statically, you might need to ensure that all symbols from `libpthread.a` are included in your program, e.g. by using:

```
-Wl,--whole-archive -pthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

N.B. you should use `-pthread` not `-lpthread` as this allows GCC to ensure it is placed at the right place in the link command.

Comment: I found that program is linked properly. After adding noexcept to a lot functions I've finally managed to narrow my problem to one line. Apparently unique_lock: "If there is no associated mutex, [throws] std::system_error with an error code of std::errc::operation_not_permitted". I cannot figure why there is no associated mutex, when it is initialized locally in class Semaphore.

Answer (score 2):

After setting functions to noexcept I was able to find stack trace showing me that I was calling condition_variable::wait() on unique_lock on mutex that did not existed. Simply the Semaphore object on which I called wait() was null. Hence the system_error with thrown by unique_lock as in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/lock